# Code shortening with while, for,,,etc?

Tags: android, while-loop

This code is messy and long, that's why I can't modify easly. I try to use `while`, `for` loop, et cetera, but I couldn't. Could you plese help me for shorten it. Thank you so much.

```
String path1 = "/storage/Folder/" + file_name;
String path2 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Folder/" + file_name;
String path3 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Folder2/" + file_name;

File file1 = new File(path1);
File file2 = new File(path2);
File file3 = new File(path3);

if (file1.exists()) {
    // do something 1
} else if (file2.exists()) {
    // do something 2
} else if (file3.exists()) {
    // do something 3
} else {
    // do something 4
}
```

I'm trying like this;

```java
String[] path_array = {path1, path2, path3};

for (String current_str : path_array) {
    File fi = new File(current_str);
    if (fi.exists()) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have stream api, you could use it like this:

```
List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
files.add(new File("/"));
files.add(new File("/"));
files.add(new File("/"));

files.stream().filter(File::exists).forEach(f -> { /* do something */ });
```

else you could do :

```
List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
files.add(new File("/"));
files.add(new File("/"));
files.add(new File("/"));

for (File file: files) {
    if(file.exists()) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loops are used for repetitive tasks. Since you "do something" different for every single file, you don't need to loop. You can use loop for File construction, but then you have to make array of File objects for later access. If you want easily understandable code (not shorter), you can try something like this, but again, your code is fine.

```
public void yourCallingMethod() {
    if(!file1Exists && !file2Exists && !file3Exists) {
        // do something 4
    }
}

public boolean file1Exists(String file_name) {
    File file = new File("/storage/Folder/" + file_name);

    if (file.exists()) {
            // do something 1
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public boolean file2Exists(String file_name) {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Folder/" + file_name);

    if (file.exists()) {
            // do something 2
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public boolean file3Exists(String file_name) {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Folder2/" + file_name);

    if (file.exists()) {
            // do something 3
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```